# 'Old fashioned' hit counter

Tags: wordpress, counter, hitcounter, hit

I can't even believe I'm asking this but I've recently moved a client over from their old website platform, circa 2011 which had their blog on blogger - one of the features being a hit counter of pageviews or visits.

Everything is now on wordpress, and the client would still like to feature a similar style hit counter on the blog posts - there are plenty of plugins around for that however for his migrated blog posts he wants the hit counter to start at the previously recorded number. There's only about 24 blogs, so I can easily set each hit counter for those posts to start from there except, can I hell find a plugin.

This goes well beyond my knowledge, and wondered if anyone out there knew of a better approach?

Cheers, 
Andy

Comment: That's what I would do to be honest (manually input the number of page views for each post) and then let whichever page views plugin you choose to use handle the rest.

Comment: Are you able to get into the database to manually edit the counts?